# How do I inject services in a service?

Tags: 8

How do I inject services in a service?

I am using the following code, but it throws an error.

```php
class RoleNegotiator implements ThemeNegotiatorInterface {

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $interface) {
    return new static(
      $interface->get('router.admin_context')
    );
  }
  public function __construct(RouteMatchInterface $route) {
    $this->route = $route;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? You should always include that.

Answer (score 12):

You define the necessary services as arguments of the service you implement.

Since you are showing a class that implements `ThemeNegotiatorInterface`, see the [theme.negotiator.default](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/theme.negotiator.default/8.2.x) service and the class implementing it, [`Drupal\Core\Theme\DefaultNegotiator`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Theme%21DefaultNegotiator.php/class/DefaultNegotiator/8.2.x).

#### Service definition

```
  theme.negotiator.default:
    class: Drupal\Core\Theme\DefaultNegotiator
    arguments: ['@config.factory']
    tags:
      - { name: theme_negotiator, priority: -100 }
```

#### Class constructor

```
public function __construct(ConfigFactoryInterface $config_factory) {
  $this->configFactory = $config_factory;
}
```

There isn't any static `create()` method as in your code.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm used to implementing `ContainerInjectionInterface` in my classes whenever I need to inject some services. In what cases would I want to define the services in my *.services.yml versus implementing `ContainerInjectionInterface`? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can recall, if you aren't replacing a service implemented by another module, you should define your service in the .services.yml file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement `ContainerInjectionInterface` as well to inject the dependency in your class (if its not a service). But if you are creating a new service you can inject it in `module.services.yml` itself as said by @kiamlaluno in his answer.

```
class RoleNegotiator implements ThemeNegotiatorInterface, ContainerInjectionInterface {

}
```